# How can I change the path of the database I want to use?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

[enter image description here][1]Helloo,I have a problem with my database and I hope someone can help me solve it.I have changed the location of my project in VS from one PC to another,and when I tried to run the project,I always get an error that "An attempt to attach the database failed.A db with the same name exists etc".My problem is that,even if I make a new one,it stores a copy in the Documents folder for no reason.Now,I don't have a database in my Documents folder,but VS keep asking for one.How can I provide the correct path for the connection?Because if i do another db,it will make a copy-although I checked "Copy to output directory" to "never" and I also established the conn string in the app.config:

```
   <add name="AnotherDb" connectionString="Data Source= 
    (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=
 C:\Users\user0101\Desktop\WPFAttendanceApp\WPFAttendanceApp\AnotherDb.mdf;
 Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I also made a confusion thinking that is something wrong with my  binding,because since the database had a copy in documents,VS had the path to the one in the docs so when I made the testing and trying to input data in the database to see if it works and can retrieve data,it didn't show anything because the other database was used.

This is what I'm getting when I want to insert data [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQFWz.png

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to get pass the error by doing a new database,right click on the database and go "properties".Once there, set the"copy to output directory" to never,"no" when asked if want to make a copy in the project(because db's default location was documents-it depends where VS saves it) and it works.In my case,it made 2 copies of the same db,and the program didn't know which one is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

You can added into you connection string just add the 'database='. This prevents SQL server to create the auto-named database

Comment: Hello,I did that but it doesn't work...I will try to make a database in azure and connect it to my code.I have to do that anyway,I guess is sooner than later.Thank you or you response!

Comment: Thank you for your response,but it didn't work as you suggested.I have managed to get pass the error by doing a new database,went to properties and set the"coupy to output directory" to never,I said no when I was asked if I want to make a copy in my project(because db's defapult location was documents) and it worked.In my case,it made 2 copies of the same db,and the program didn't know which one is the correct one.

Comment: Hey there! Brilliant news to hear you fixed this! Sure post your response as an answer and answer your own question in case someone else has the same issue in the future :)

Comment: Great,i'll do that!Thanks!